# Undo CSS cascading behavior

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

CSS Markup:

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-current-day">
    <a href="#" class="ui-state-default ui-state-active">17</a>
</td>
```

[CSS Rules](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css):

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default
{
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #E6E6E6;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active
{
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    color: #212121;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

When the active class is added, it overrides the default styles which is normal. But I do not want this behavior. I want to restore the styles added (overridden) by the `ui-state-active` class back to the values specified in `ui-state-default` with minimum fuss: without altering original CSS and/or removing the class. <strike>Something like:</strike>

```
.ui-state-active {
background: inherit;
}
```

seemed to work but I am not sure if this is right.

## Edit

It is possible for me to add classes on the parent, like this:

```
<td class="ui-datepicker-current-day DISABLE-STATE-ACTIVE-CLASS">
    <a href="#" class="ui-state-default ui-state-active">17</a>
</td>
```

Comment: be careful, 'inherit' won't 'restore' any value that has been applied via another class, but instead look for a corresponding value up the inheritance chain.

Comment: @schellmax: understood, instead of up, i need to remove/disable styles on an element added by classes other than the first one.

Comment: Why don't you want to remove the class?

Comment: @Josh: good question. The classes are added by jquery ui's datepicker. I won't hack into the code but if it is possible somehow by hooking into one of the callbacks provided by the datepicker I am willing to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you want the background to display?

Inherit will work if you always want this td to inherit its background from its parent. That being said, in general that IS how you handle overrides in css. Either override the style setting inline, with a overridden style in a `<style>` tag that has equal or higher priority, or an overridden style with an `!important` tag.

In your example, it looks to me like `background: inherit` should be just fine but if that doesn't work for you, you can always try the old standby of `background: transparent`.

Comment: Just want to note that I think your characterization of `!important` is a little misleading. It is not meant to simply "override" CSS—which is what would happen anyway, if you were to make new rules on the same selector—but rather to override without respect to specificity. I've found that if one has many `!important`s in their stylesheet, they probably don't understand much about specificity and/or don't care, either of which will lead to a mess eventually.

Comment: Correct, `!important` is best saved for absolute desperation as it is the shotgun approach.

Comment: I managed to do it by putting the calendar inside a div with an ID, then wrote css rule `#customdatepicker .ui-state-default{background: #E6E6E6;border-color: #D3D3D3;}`. important or not, browser seemed to override the background color even when cells had `ui-state-highlight`/`ui-state-active` classes applied.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why this 'seems to work', it clearly shouldn't. in case there is no other element in the inheritance chain having 'background' defined, the value should be re-set to 'transparent' (which is the default value).

you can't make a declaration 'undone' this way, albeit there might be good reasons for trying to do so (as in your case). i guess the only way to get back to the background value defined in 'ui-state-default' is removing the 'ui-state-active' class from the dom element. this will involve making changes to the plugins js code, and it's clear why you wanted to avoid this.

why not simply setting the same color in the css? just a few clicks in themeroller :)

Comment: You're right, i don't want inherit as this goes *up*, I need to go side ways... inherit from the first class defined on an element (*ui-state-default* ui-state-active). I am using ui-datepicker *inline* with a complicated onSelect and beforeShowDay and lots of background colors. The today (uistate-highlight) and clicked day (uistate-active) become yellow and white respectively which I do not want as I use these colors to indicate something else.